# Step by Step install no sql oracle database

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, nosql

How can I install nosql oracle database on ubuntu ? I need all step please

I didin't found a tutorial how to install with all details about

Comment: did you check this ? https://docs.oracle.com/database/nosql-12.1.3.4/AdminGuide/installation.html

Comment: yes but it does not accept the admin parameter and when I do noadmin and I try to access the kv interface I need an admin

Comment: can you put in the question how are you calling the java KVHOME/lib/kvstore.jar ? I guess this is the part where you are having errors. If not, provide a step by step and tell us where your process is failing

Comment: badr@badr-VirtualBox:~/u01/kv-19.5.19/lib$ java -jar kvstore.jar runadmin -port 5000 -host localhost

Comment: In this step  I had this warning : badr@badr-VirtualBox:~/u01$ java -jar kv-19.5.19/lib/kvstore.jar makebootconfig -root KVStore/ -port 5000 -admin 5001 -host localhost -harange 5010,5100 -capacity 3 -store-security none
    WARNING: the -admin argument is obsolete and was benignly ignored.